# Docusign Connector not available in library settings of custom document library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, docusignapi

I have created a custom document library using Visual Studio in Sharepoint 2010. When i deploy the docusign it is available on other Document libraries that was created directly on site but is not available with the custom form i have created using the Visual Studio. The Docusign connector is also not available with the "Permissions and Management" in the Library settings of the custom form but is available with the other document library settings.

Any ideas ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The installer script will install the DocuSign Sharepoint connector for any `SPList` of `BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary (1)` and the `Hidden property == false`.